# Trying to develop python in emacs

Tags: python, emacs, gnu

I am trying to follow the setup on http://hide1713.wordpress.com/2009/01/30/setup-perfect-python-environment-in-emacs/

I have steps 1 - 3 running great.

Then I get to part 4: Setup Rope, Ropemacs and Pymacs.

We need the latest development version of Rope and Ropemacs. Otherwise, emacs can not find the rope-completions function.
I just copy’n paste from Ryan’s website. You can find the original post here

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
mkdir /tmp/rope && cd /tmp/rope
hg clone http:// bitbucket . org/agr/rope
hg clone http:// bitbucket . org/agr/ropemacs
hg clone http:// bitbucket . org/agr/ropemode
sudo easy_install rope
ln -s ../ropemode/ropemode ropemacs/
sudo easy_install ropemacs
```

I am running GNU Emacs 22.0.97.1 on OS 10.4.11

I tried running this through terminal but i get the error: sudo: apt-get: command not found

Comment: Please use code blocks for your command list.

Comment: -1 for assuming we should know what OS you're talking about when you say 'OS 10.4.11'

Comment: @Falmarri, I'm pretty sure everyone reading this knows that the OP dropped the "X" from "OS X 10.4.11".  +1 to undo your -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apt-get is only on Debian-based systems like Ubuntu and *buntu.  RPM distributions use a variety of other systems, but yum seems to be predominant.

Since you're on a Mac, install [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/).  You'll need to install XCode first, which you can get from Apple after you register (for free).

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to [`el-get`](http://tapoueh.org/articles/news/_el-get.html), it's really nice to install and keep all your elisp extensions up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

Well, apt-get is the package manager for Debian-based Linux systems. It will not exist on most Macs. Whatever programs Ryan wants you to install (using apt-get) you will have to try to install in the appropriate way for Mac OS X.

You did mean you were using Mac OS X, right?